# Why do encamped Stormcloaks not fight when I attack a Thalmor patrol on a road nearby and carry the battle to them?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I met a Thalmor patrol escorting a Thalos worshipper at Location: 60164, -80436, Internal ID: 2358 (road between Helgen and Ivarstead) and ambushed them South of the Falkreath Stormcloak Camp (39501, -74990, Internal ID: 329). I tried to carry the fight into the camp for the Stormcloaks to be inadvertedly being attacked and therefore to join battle on my side. But they kept fleeing the Thalmor despite outnumbering them.
I wore Legion armour that time but have not joined the Legion.

Comment: I wonder if it is indeed the Legion armor. You do not need to join the Legion to wear their armor, so it's possible that some radiant AI makes it so the Stormcloak soldiers will not align with you. Perhaps even, if you have not picked a side in the civil war questline, they simply do not care about you at all.

Comment: Thanks @Kaizerwolf, that's most possibly true. There was a strange remark about my armour from one of the Stormcloaks though, so the AI does make a difference out of it. What I wonder is why NPCs don't start to fight each other despite being hostile towards each other by action.

Comment: The armor you wear in Skyrim does not matter for AI behavior. You can wear legion armor near stormcloaks and not be attacked for example, but if you join the legion and wear stormcloak armor near stormcloaks they will attack you. They just know your allegiance somehow. Its kind of a shame that a disguise mechanic was not implemented.

Comment: @JamesFaix do you have a source for that claim? I'm curious!

Comment: First paragraph [here](https://en.m.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Factions), also my observed experience after playing for a long time.